# modify the font-size for html tag using media queries

Tags: css

I am unable to modify the **font-size** of the body and **html** tag. I'm trying to change the texts of my page using **rem** (I understand that this measure is based on the html or body tag, I'm not sure). if I use rem, it would simply be enough to modify the size of the font-size in the mentioned tags, and so my content would change in size. I am right? or what is the best practice? thank you very much.

```
html, body{
 font-size: 12px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  html, body{
  font-size: 12px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
 html{
 font-size: 13px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) { 
 html{
 font-size: 14px !important;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 html{
  font-size: 15px !important;
  } 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a0s4qt8w/

Comment: change the sequence of media queries and consider changing `min` to `max`

Answer (score 0):

Change the sequence of media queries and consider changing `min` to `max` width.

```css
p::after,
p {
  font-size: 12px;
  content: ", 12px";
}

@media (max-width: 999px) {
  p::after,
  p {
    font-size: 14px;
    content: ", 14px";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  p::after,
  p {
    font-size: 13px;
    content: ", 13px";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 568px) {
  p::after,
  p {
    font-size: 11px;
    content: ", 11px";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  p::after,
  p {
    font-size: 10px;
    content: ", 10px";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the font size changes when you change the screen size. Try putting font sizes with larger differences in your fiddle, say 10, 14, 18 and 24px. I did, and the sizes obviously changed.

To explain Arvind's answer a bit: you can use `min-width` as you have it (although your lowest value is redundant — in effect, your code is saying that the font size is 12px on any screen smaller than 768px). However, it's more common practice to use `max-width` and go from large to small as Arvind has it.

To see plenty of examples, google "responsive @media css" or something similar.

Also, `rem` is based on the `html` tag, not the `body` tag. [Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_rem) an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using inline styles and ascend the order from most to least and be more specific of which content you want to reduce the size of. In case of using inline styles use `!important` to override the previously styled element or try using its parent class to change it.

ps: I removed the inline style here

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a0s4qt8w/15/

```css
   p{font-size:18px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

  html, body, p{
    font-size: 15px;
  }
 }
 
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) { 
  html, body, p{
    font-size: 14px;
  }
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 

 html, body, p{
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}


 @media screen and (max-width: 576px) { 
  html, body, p{
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  }
```

```html
     <div style="height:   100vh; display:   flex; flex-direction:   column; justify-content: center; align-items:center;">
          <p>
           mi mamá me mima mame mi mo mu
            <br>
             <br>
            *indicaciones <br>
            *indicacion chulas <br>
            *indicaciones pedras<br>

          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  
          </p>
      </div>
```